# Topology generated by a sub basis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S=\{ (a,\infty): a \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Clearly S is a sub basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as their union in whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Now I'm interested in finding the topology generated by $S$. I think it is the collection of all intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every* subcollection of $\wp(\mathbb R)$ serves as a *subbasis* for a topology on $\mathbb R$.

In your case subbasis $\mathcal S$ appears to be a *basis* as well. This because it covers $\mathbb R$ and is closed under finite intersections.

In that case the topology generated by $\mathcal S$ can be described as the collection of sets that can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal S$.

Denoting this topology by $\tau$ we have $$\tau=\{\cup\mathcal T\mid \mathcal T\subseteq\mathcal S\}$$

and we find $\varnothing=\cup\varnothing\in\tau$ and $\mathbb R=\cup\mathcal S\in\tau$.

If $\cup\mathcal T\notin\{\varnothing,\mathbb R\}$ then it can be shown that $\cup\mathcal T=(a,\infty)\in\mathcal S$ where $a:=\inf(\cup\mathcal T)\in\mathbb R$.

Final conclusion: $\tau=\mathcal S\cup\{\varnothing,\mathbb R\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you also include $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $\varnothing$, then yes. Note that these two open sets can't be written in that way for any $a\in \mathbb R$. But you are essentially correct, remembering to include the two extreme cases.

The reason is that the union or intersection of any finite collection of such intervals is another such interval. If you have an infinite collection of intervals of the form $(-n,\infty)$ with $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, the union is the whole space. And if the collection is empty, so is its union.